# perl unable to open the contents of the file

Tags: perl

i was trying to open and read the contents of file in directory. i can access the directory and get the list of files.but i am getting error like unable to open and read the contents inside the file.please help

```
 #usr/bin/perl
    my $dir='d:\task';
    opendir DIR,$dir or die "cannot open directory";
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) 
    {

     next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
     print " $file \n";
     open(my $fh,'<',$file) or die "unable to open the $file ";
     while(my $row=<$fh>)
     {
     chomp $row;
     print "$row";
      }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Add `use strict; use warnings;` 2. Add `$!` to your `die` messages to get information about the errors. 3. Profit.

Comment: thanks. it lists the file.but during opening of a file it is saying no such file or directory.

Comment: You need either a `chdir` or a path. Or just use `foreach my $file glob ( "D:\task\*" ) { `

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the newlines from your files? It will make all your file content end up on one line. I would suggest using globbing unless you really need to use `readdir`, e.g. `for my $file (<d:/task/*>) ... `

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the filenames in context of the directory, whereas you are probably running the code from another directory.

To open the file, you will need to prepend the directory path:

```
open (my $in, '<', "$dir/$file") or die "Cannot open file for input: $!\n";
```

Comment: hay thank you so much. is it possible to take directory name as input from user from console and open it?

Comment: Yes of course. Try `my $dir = <STDIN>'; chomp $dir;`

Comment: @dland Or chomp it _en passant_: `chomp(my $dir = <STDIN>);`